# Measuring code coverage in ROS

Tags: ros, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am looking for a solution to measure code coverage in ROS. For example, in the ROS `turtlesim` package, I would like to measure how many functions / branches / program-blocks the tutorial program `draw_square.cpp` reaches during its execution. Such coverage can be helpful, for example,  in determining the thoroughness of a test program.

The ROS Continuous Integration page (http://wiki.ros.org/CIs) provides hints on some existing solutions of measuring coverage, but the page does not seem to  give details.

For your information, I sometimes used GCOV for measuring C program coverage. I am looking for  a solution that can deal with both C++ and Python programs in ROS.

Thank  you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/322122/measuring-code-coverage-in-ros/) by [Zhoulai Fu](https://answers.ros.org/users/34164/zhoulai-fu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 186 on 2019-04-29

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-04-29**:
Perhaps [mikeferguson/code_coverage](https://github.com/mikeferguson/code_coverage) can help here, or at least the C++ side. For Python I wouldn't know anything integrated/nice/ROS wrapped.

Edit: according to [this](https://sr-build-tools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ansible/roles/ci/doc/modules/#list-of-modules) the `sr-build-tools` project can provide code coverage for both C++ and Python. Haven't used it myself though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have an example of doing code coverage using gcov for ROS C++ code at [node_example](https://github.com/tdenewiler/node_example#testing). The tests are run as part of a Travis job and the results are uploaded to [codecov](https://codecov.io/gh/tdenewiler/node_example), but you can also get the coverage results locally as well.

The relevant steps for doing code coverage of a ROS package can be found in the Travis configuration file at:

https://github.com/tdenewiler/node_example/blob/master/.travis.yml#L134

That package does not yet include tests for Python code.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) with karma: 4347 on 2019-04-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Zhoulai Fu](https://answers.ros.org/users/34164/zhoulai-fu/) on 2020-10-16**:
Link not working.

**Comment by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) on 2020-10-16**:
I switched from Travis CI to Github Actions. The same approach is used. https://github.com/tdenewiler/node_example/blob/main/.github/workflows/test.yml